# Unable to read memory - class variable

Tags: c++

I have the following classes:

**Main.cpp**

```
Display* display_obj;
void display_wrapper()
{
    display_obj->display();
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //...
    State* s = new State(100);

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape_wrapper);
    display_obj->setState(s);
    //...
}
```

**Display.h**

```
class Display
{
public:
    Display(){}
    ~Display(){};

    void display();
    void setState(State*);

private:
    State* state;
};

//...

void Display::setState(State* s)
{
    state = s;
}
```

**State.h**

```
class State
{
public:
    State(){};
    State(int);
    ~State(){};

private:
    GLint timer;
    Floor floor;
};

State::State(int t)
{
    timer = t;

    FloorLogical floorLogical;
    floor = floorLogical.createFloor();
}
```

When i run the code i get the following exception in the instruction:

> state = s;

Exception:
Unhandled exception at 0x00F96719 in project_name.exe: 0xC0000006: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

What is wrong?

Comment: I don't see any code that allocates an object and assigns it to `display_obj`.

Comment: Did you instantiate display_obj?

Comment: I forgot to instantiate it! Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display_obj is not initialized. You need to initialize that variable before you can use it.

Comment: It may be initialized, but to NULL/nullptr. It need to be set to point to a valid instance of `Display`.